# Travel to Europe with a criminal record - Can I enter the country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, denial-of-entry, criminal-records

I am a passport holder from a visa waiver country to Europe. I am planning to travel to Europe for my next vacation. I am asking because I think there could be a problem regarding my entry into the country. I committed a minor crime and paid a fine (300 euros) while in one of the European countries over 5 years ago.

**How likely do you think it is that I will be denied entry or deported because of this?**

I have already asked the Consulate and they have told me that "I still do not need to apply for a visa" and "that the border police will make the final decision."

I am waiting for comments from anyone who has traveled to Europe under similar circumstances.
Or even if you are not in a similar situation.

- Questions that travelers from visa waiver countries are asked at immigration
- Being asked about past criminal history when traveling to Europe
- People you know who were not allowed to enter Europe and why, etc.

Any comments will help me.

Thank you in advance.

ーー

Additional information:
Crime is theft (shoplifting) at Scandinavian countries.
And I am planning a trip to Southern Europe (Italy, Spain, Greece, etc.).

Comment: Was it really a crime or rather a misdemeanor? The amount of the fine would point to the latter, IMO.

Comment: @dunni traditionally in English law a misdemeanor _is_ a crime, a minor crime, as opposed to a felony.  The UK has since done away with these terms but they persist in other systems derived from English law, notably including the US.

Comment: I suppose immigration will make a difference according to the severity of the crime. A single case of shoplifting vs. Several armed robberies, for example.